# Pepper robot - Date_Dance.crg

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/getting_started/samples/sample_dance1.html

Hello,
    I am a newbie in Pepper Robot programming. As a programming exercise, I imported a project from Date_Dance.crg which I found from the above link, and followed the directions described in “Try it!” section.
    I can run the app by pressing the green right arrow button or selecting the app from App Launcher on the tablet, however, the app cannot be triggered by any of the triggering sentences: “date dance”, “Pepper’s date dance”, “dance I’m fresh you’re pretty”, “Fresh and pretty dance”. I also tried by using Application title by saying: “start Date Dance”. However, it doesn’t work either.

Could anyone guess or explain why it fails to my voice command?

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- Autonomous Life isn't activated on Pepper
- Autonomous Life is activated, but the robot isn't listening (blue eyes), maybe because it hasn't seen you
- Pepper is just in the wrong language
- Or you don't have the special dialog applauncher package that is required for that to work (it's usually installed on robots along with other apps like the tablet app launcher, but it may be missing on yours ?) - maybe do an app update, or ask whoever provided you with the robot (there can be several different configurations depending of the robot use case, though I believe most of them have the dialog applauncher)